# Clean method for declaring models

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express

I have a node project that uses express, [orm](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2) and sqlite3.

I have multiple models. Currently each model is declared similar to this:

```
var orm = require('orm');
var db = orm.connect({database: ':memory:', protocol: 'sqlite'});
var schema = db.define('service', {
    uptime: Number,
    // ...
});
db.sync(function (err) {
    !err && console.log("db synced!");
});
module.exports = schema;
```

No particularly pleasant across a dozen models to repeatedly require and connect.

I would like to tidy it up so I can connect in the `app.js` and then load in the models and use them as I normally would in the routes.  However I can't get it working.  This is what I am doing:

First I define the connect and define the models in `app.js`:

```
var service;
orm.connect(app.get('db-opt'), function(err,db){
    !err && console.log("db connected!");
    if (err){
        throw err;
    }
    db.load('./models', function(err){
        app.service = service = db.models.service;
        !err && console.log("models loaded!");
    });
    db.sync(function(err){
        !err && console.log("db synced!");
    });
});
```

The `models/index.js` file looks like:

```
module.exports = function(db,fn){
    db.define('service', {
        uptime: Number,
        // ...
    });
    return fn();
};
```

And the `routes/services.js` looks like:

```
var services = [];

exports.list = function(service){
    return function(req, res){
        service.find({}, function(err, services){
            if (err){
                return next(err);
            }
            res.render('services', {
                title: 'Services',
                services: services
            });
        });
    };
};
```

And finally I connect the route like this in app.js:

```
app.get('/services', services.list(service));
```

I get the expected console messages but soon as I try to visit I get the following error:
`TypeError: Cannot call method 'find' of undefined`.

I have tried passing `app.service` and `models.service` to service.list but neither works giving the same error.

How can I cleanly load the models and have them accessible to the routes that require them?

**Update**: I can prove that the `db.load` call is working with the following code:

```
db.load('./models', function(err){
    var services = [];
    service = db.models.service;
    service.find({}, function(err, services) {
        if (err){
            throw err;
        }
    });
    !err && console.log("models loaded!");
});
```

As this gives a `Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: service`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I was close.  I was under the assumption that the `app.get('/', services.list(service));` would be called with whatever value was in service when it was invoked.  So despite `app.get(...)` being executed (possibly) before the callback of `orm.connect` everything would be resolved correctly after the `http.createServer(app)`.  Not so.

Moving the `app.get(..)` to within the orm.connect call back causes it to work.

Thus:

```
// define models
var db = orm.connect(app.get('db-opt'), function(err,db){
    !err && console.log("db connected!");
    if (err){
        throw err;
    }
    db.load('./models', function(err){
        app.service = db.models.service;
        !err && console.log("models loaded!");
    });
    db.sync(function(err){
        !err && console.log("db synced!");
    });

    app.get('/', services.list(app.service));
    // ...
});
```

While this is the method I will use, can anyone see a different way?